# Пунктуация. Двоеточие, кавычки

Tags: пунктуация

Как следовало бы расставить знаки в этом предложении?
*На этом форуме, к сожалению, если в посте употребляются слова "Родина и патриотизм", то заканчивается этот пост словами "зомбированный или раб".*
1. Я бы двоеточие перед открывающимися кавычками опустил из-за тесной связи слов (как и оставил в тексте).
2. Стоит ли "Родина", "патриотизм", "зомбированный", "раб" брать в отдельные кавычки? На мой взгляд, "Родина и патриотизм" в одних кавычках - хорошо, т.к. в предложении сказано, что *оба* слова "в посте употребляются". Но в случае с "зомбированный или раб", у меня сомнения в "или". Думается, что нужно записывать так: *...словами "зомбированный" или "раб".*
Что скажете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаемый вариант (с небольшой редакцией):

На этом форуме, к сожалению, если в посте употребляются **слова** "родина и патриотизм", то  в нем обязательно присутствуют такие **выражения**, как  "зомбированный или раб".

Слова, выражения ― это приложения перед "родина и патриотизм" и т.д., поэтому не нужно двоеточия.

Отдельные кавычки не нужны, так как присутствуют союзы И/ИЛИ.

Не стоит использовать прописные буквы, высокий смысл слова "родина" понятен и так.

Comment: "Зомбированный" - это выражение? Или все-таки слово? А "раб"?

Comment: Это слово, и выражение тоже,  и даже лексемой в некотором роде можете назвать.  Читаем словарь: ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ,  4. Слово, фраза, оборот речи.  Не рекомендуется в одном предложении  дважды употреблять одно слово, это лексический повтор. А то слово, ещё слово, еще одно слово.

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие здесь не ставится, поскольку нет обобщающего слова, да и перечисление состоит всего из двух пунктов. А отдельные кавычки, безусловно, нужны.

P.S. Сама фраза довольно кривая.